# Converting cartesian to polar coordinates

Tags: polar-coordinates

I am trying to find a way to convert cartesian to polar coordinates.

A quick search gives me:

$$r^2=x^2+y^2$$

$$θ=\arctan(y/x)$$

so far so good, but what happens when $x=0$. I know in that case theta is $\pi/2$ but how can I compute that from a computer point of view? or should I just make a special case?

Comment: $x=rcos\theta$ ;$y=rsin\theta$. That should help you in computation.

Comment: I am trying to find the thetha, not the other way around

Comment: In case you are asking how to bypass "Division by zero error", make it very small $10^-10$ or even smaller than that. You cannot put $x=0$ and expect a value from $arctan$.

Comment: [The second equation is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Comment: If you're purely looking at programming, I would suggest that you use existing libraries like `math.atan2` for python. This will be much more efficient than writing it by yourself as you have a lot of tolerance problems behind the scene.

Answer (score 1):

read $ x$

read $ y$

$r :=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

if $ x> 0 $ then $\theta=\arctan(\frac yx)$

if $ x<0 $ then $ \theta=\arctan(\frac yx) +\pi$

if $ x=0 $ and $y>0$ then $\theta=\frac \pi 2$

if $ x=0$ and $y<0$ then $\theta = -\frac \pi 2$

Comment: If $x<0$ then $\theta\neq\arctan(y/x)$

Comment: @enzotib Thanks . i just edited.

Comment: I wonder how well behaved this is around x=0. For example there is exponent overflow if y=10^5 and x=10^-320. (A small x value could theoretically arise from rounding errors on a value that is nominally 0.) Any algorithm that uses floating point equality is suspicious. Instead I would recommend breaking the plane into four quadrants and test x>y and x>-y.